# Install Myeclipse shows a java error

Tags: java, macos, myeclipse

When I install myeclipse, it shows "needs java SE6 Environment",
How do I resolve this problem?

I have already installed jdk1.7 in my OS X Yosemite.

```
 /Users/**** $ java -version
 java version "1.7.0_75"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Check your JDK version in MyEclipse if it is JDK1.6 then change it to JDK 1.7 and change the JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the online installer, which is a 32-bit application while Java 7 on OS X is 64-bit only.

You have two solutions :  you can just download the offline installer, which should work fine, according to [this support thread](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/myeclipse-2015-ci-os-x-installer-requires-java-6/).

If this doesn't work, you'll have to install Java 6, which you can find [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US).

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with earlier installers. All current installers will not have this problem. Please download the latest release.

Comment: you mean myeclipse installer? or java installer?